# render throws error AttributeError META - (Exception location: __getattr__ in urllib2)

Tags: python, django, urllib2, attributeerror

I followed [this](http://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/magic-links/) article to try to load images from an external website. I am trying to pull all the images from an external link. I have used BeautifulSoup to parse the link and get all the required links.

Before the view calls the render() function at the end of the code, image_list and return_dict have the desired values. However the render function seems to be generating the AttributeError exception. Please assist.

I get the following error:

```
    AttributeError at /post/add_new/
    META
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/post/add_new/
    Django Version: 1.4.1
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
    META
    Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py in __getattr__, line 225
    Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\Talal\\Python Workspace\\talal_ynd',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\ipython-0.13-py2.7.egg',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyreadline-2.0_dev1-py2.7-win32.egg',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pil-1.1.7-py2.7-win32.egg',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
     'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
     'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
     'C:\\Python27',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Thu, 13 Sep 2012 17:30:45 +0500
```

Here is my view file:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from posts.models import Post, PostForm
from django.template.loader import get_template
from talal_ynd.settings import TEMPLATE_DIRS


def post_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            success_message = 'Thank you.'

            link = post_form.cleaned_data['link']
            if 'get_link' in request.POST:
                import urllib2
                request = urllib2.Request(link)
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                html=response.read()
                from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
                soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
                import re
                title=''; description=''
                description=soup.findAll('meta',
                    attrs={'name':re.compile("description$",
                        re.I)})[0].get('content')
                try: 
                    title=soup.findAll('meta',
                        attrs={'name':re.compile("^title$",re.I)})[0].get('content')
                except:
                    pass
                if not title:
                    title=soup.title.string
                max_images=10
                image_tags=soup.findAll('img',limit=max_images)
                image_urls_list=[]
                image_urls_list2=[]
                from urlparse import urljoin
                for image_tag in image_tags:
                    url=image_tag.get('src')
                    #image_urls_list.append(request.build_absolute_uri(url))#urljoin(link,url))#HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(url))
                    #image_urls_list.append(request.urljoin(link,url))
                    image_urls_list.append(url)
                image_list=[]
                for url in image_urls_list:
                    image_list.append({'url':url})
                return_dict={'title':title, 'description':description}
                return_dict.update({'images':image_list})

            else:
                post_form = PostForm()
    else:

        post_form = PostForm()


    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've overwritten the `request` variable inside your function, because you reused it for the call to `urllib2.Request`. Use a different variable name there.

Comment: Not really, that is the main problem (apart from some style issues, eg you should be putting your imports at the top of the file, not interspersed in the code). Make sure you've restarted your dev server.

Comment: Sorry, turns out I was editing the wrong version of the code. Thanks!! this solved the problem!

Comment: i have the same problem and I can't believe I was so dumb enough not to realize i over wrote it!